# HtmlUnit java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE

Tags: java, web-scraping, htmlunit

I'm trying to scrap link using HtmlUnit but it's showing Error on (webClient.getPage(url);) line.

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Start {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        String url = "http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/dependency-info.html";
        webClient.getPage(url);
    }

}
```

This code showing me this error log.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:146)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.configureHttpsScheme(HttpWebConnection.java:625)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.createHttpClient(HttpWebConnection.java:557)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getHttpClientBuilder(HttpWebConnection.java:518)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:170)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1397)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1315)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:394)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:315)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:463)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:448)
at example.com.scrapper.Start.main(Start.java:14)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
```

Please Help!

Comment: This looks like a dependency issue. May be the Class you are looking for is present in two different jars on your CP.

Comment: How are you building your project? If you are using maven please include the output of mvn help:dependency-tree

Comment: @tgdavies I'm using gradle to add dependency.

Comment: Please add the output of `gradle dependencies` to your question,

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is facing this issue, keep only pom.xml file version under `".m2\repository\net\sourceforge\htmlunit\<all folders>"`. I removed other versions, and it's working now.